# MYSQL Roundcube mail id problems

Tags: php, mysql, roundcube, iredmail

Okay so I am using iRedmail on a linux ubuntu 14.01
I am trying to configure my password plugin and have granted all the necessary privileges, but I am at the following error:

> Mar 24 13:31:59 MailServer roundcube: <7vd67dj0> DB Error: [1054] Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL Query: UPDATE users SET crypt=ENCRYPT('Password1',CONCAT(_utf8'$5$',RIGHT(MD5(RAND()),8),_utf8'$')) WHERE id='lauren' LIMIT 1) in /opt/www/roundcubemail-1.1.4/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_db.php on line 543 (POST /mail/?_task=settings&_action=plugin.password-save?_task=&_action=)

It is trying to put it in Database: Roundcubemail Table: id
When I search though mysql I have Database: Roundcubemail Table: users

I cannot seem to find where in the files it is calling "id" because I know its as simple as changing it to "users"

Any help here?